# Container with text overflow not being obeyed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an angular App where I am displaying a drop down which in general works.  However, when the form is displayed on a mobile screen or your browser is resized to small.  The drop down sometimes displays on the next line i.e. not next to the label.

I have figured out that this only happens when the selected item in the drop down is longer than the container itself.  Ideally, the dropdown should behave like the other inputs in the form and have the maximum width of its container and therefore obey the text-overflow.

This is basically a boostrap form...I have provided an example and taken the guts out of the dropdown as I have found the offending elements so just need some css help in making this work.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/glenhong/pen/abqqMZw)

```
<div class="small-container">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-label">Label 1</label>
    <div class="col-container">
      <input type="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-label">Label 2</label>
    <div class="col-container">
      <div class='ng-select'>
        <div class="ng-select-container">
          <div class="ng-value-container">
            <div class="ng-value">
              <span>This is a very long select option</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.small-container {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px
    
}

.col-label {
  width: 150px;
}

.col-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.col-container input {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 12px
}

.ng-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.ng-select-container {
  border: solid 1px #111;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ng-value-container,
.ng-value{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is what it looks like when there is enough room to display the contents..

[image]

And when there is not

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```css
.target {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you want to add ellipsis (`...`) whenever text overflows, the use:

```css
.target {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This is generally good practice to indicate to the user that some text is hidden.

Comment: I have this in the css styles.... ive updated the code.  It is also in the codepen

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting hidden to an element know that you ought to set the height or width or both of them try this

```
.ng-value{
Height:10px;
Overflow: hidden;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hmmmm... it does not

Comment: Did you try using height?

Comment: I just saw the code pen code, you set the width of the input field to 100% meaning you want it to display in full, I set it to 40px and it was perfect then set  the height to 22px

Comment: Yes ultimately I dont want to set a width... the form will be responsive i.e it could be mobile or it could be full screen.  I just want it to occupy all availble width of the container and not wrap to the next line

Comment: Then use grid system

Comment: ```display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "Label . Input";```  try it on the style.....  To make it responsive.